# Make use of short and definition-available virtual methods for optimization?

Tags: c++, optimization

I am just wondering if most compilers can do the following optimization

```
class A
{
    virtual void f() { m = 5; }
    void g() { f(); }
    int m;
};
```

`f()` is a virtual function and thus is not inline. However, can the compiler optimize `g()` for calling `f()` as inline since the definition of `f()` is short and available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think they can. Here's why:

```
class B : public A
{
   virtual void f() {}
}

B b;
b.g(); // This must result in B::f() getting called.
```

Answer (score 5):

> can the compiler optimize g() for calling f() as inline since the definition of f() is short and available?

That's pretty convoluted.  `g()` can be inlined, such that calling `A::g()` generates the same optimised code as calling `A::f()`.  If you derive from `A`, `g()` can still be inlined *regardless* of whether it's called on a variable for which runtime type is known at compile time or via an `A*` or `A&` to an object of unknown runtime type.

But, that's got nothing to do with `f()` being "short and available" - so I'm guessing your intent is to ask whether `f()` itself can be inlined: sometimes, specifically - when the runtime type is known at compile time `f()` itself may be inlined too.

```
struct B : A { void f() { ... } }
B b;
b.g();  // g() and B::f() may be inlined
A* p = &b;
p->g(); // g() and B::f() may be inlined (latter iff optimiser tracks p addressing a B)
p = opaque_factory();  // definition not known to compiler
p->g(); // equivalent to p->f();, g() inline, f() dispatched virtually / not inline.

void x(A* p) { p->g(); }  // g() may be inlined
x(p); // iff x is inlined, g() and B::f() may be too - per p->g() call above
      // iff x is out-of-line, and compiler doesn't do full-program analysis and find
      //    it's only ever called for a specific runtime type (unlikely if not a
      //    single-translation-unit program), then dispatch to f() can not be inlined
      //    and must be virtual
```

By not just declaring but actually defining `g()` (i.e. providing implementation) in the class definition, you implicitly tell the compiler `g()` can be inline.

The lack of overhead of `g()` is one reason the [Non Virtual Interface idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-virtual_interface_pattern) (where the virtual functions are made non-public and accessed via non-virtual public functions, allowing easy later customisation of the base class wrapper function to add instrumentation/logging etc. if needed) is attractive - there's no performance cost in optimised builds while extra functionality's not (yet) been added.

Comment: I believe you wrote volatile instead of virtual :)